# Springboot/ tomcat / apache reverse proxy , which of those applications is setting the reponse header

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache, tomcat, proxypass

I've a springBoot (without security) application running in Tomcat and with Apache reverse proxy on the server.
When making a POST request, the status 403 is returned.

I suspect Tomcat or apache reverse proxy to be responsible for returning 403.
Which information in the HTTP request or HTTP response is causing the 403 return code ?
And how can I fix it ?

[image]

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${open-api}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

httpd.conf

```
SSLCipherSuite 'kEECDH+ECDSA kEECDH kEDH HIGH +SHA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !MEDIUM !MD5 !EXP !DSS !PSK !SRP !kECDH SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 2048
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

DocumentRoot /apache/htdocs

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine   On
  RewriteRule     ^/(.*)$   https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1    [redirect,last]
  <Directory /apache/htdocs>
    Require all granted
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine On
  <Directory /apache/htdocs>
    Require all granted
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.guli.com/fullchain.pem"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.guli.com/privkey.pem"
</VirtualHost>


<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  <Location "/">
    ProxyPass "http://localhost:50080/main/" connectiontimeout=5 timeout=600
    ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:50080/main/"
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath "/main/" "/"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"
  </Location>
# so läuft mal: http://www.guli.com
  <Location "/email">
    ProxyPass "http://localhost:50099/email"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:50099/email"
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath "/email" "/"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Prefix "/email"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
  </Location>
# /ta/swagger-ui.html 
  <Location "/ta">
    ProxyPass "http://localhost:50086/ta"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:50086/ta"
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath "/ta" "/"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Prefix "/ta"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
  </Location>
# pres/swagger-ui.html
  <Location "/pres">
    ProxyPass "http://localhost:50083/pres"
    ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:50083/pres"
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath "/pres" "/"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Prefix "/pres"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
  </Location>
  <Location "/guli-web">
    ProxyPass "http://localhost:50096/guliadmin-web" connectiontimeout=5 timeout=600
    ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:50096/guliadmin-web"
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath "/guliadmin-web" "/guliadmin-web"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
  </Location>
  <Location "/.well-known">
    ProxyPass "!"
  </Location>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyVia Off
  ProxyStatus On
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That's your application. Additional headers might have been added by the other components, but the status line comes from the application.

Comment: But my application doesn't implement any security at all.  There is no dependency on spring-security. See pom.xml that I added

Comment: @f1sh Not necessarily, an intermediate layer like a proxy, load-balancer or gateway could require authentication before it gets forwarded to the actual application.

Comment: Can you share the apache configuration?

Comment: Just added the apache file :  httpd.conf

Comment: @f1sh if the configurations kept the default values, we would expect Apache-Coyote as a Server response header, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

We see the response headers being set in the / *Location* while there's a /ta *Location* section.
As says the [Location documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#location), the sections are processed in the order they appear, which means the / should logically be the last section.